# missing ) after argument list, When trying to call JS function onclick

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to add data to a JSON object, stored in session. I do this with a js function:

```
<section class="products">
    @foreach (var prod in Model) {
        string path = "~/images/" + prod.ImgURL;
        <article>
            <a href="@Url.Action("InspectProduct","Products", new {productID = prod.Id})">
            <img src="@Url.Content(path)" style="max-width: 75%"></a>

            <h3><a href="@Url.Action("InspectProduct","Products")">@prod.Name</a></h3>
            <h4>@prod.Price,-</h4>
            <a class="btn-add" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="addToJSONObject(@prod.Id, @prod.Name, @prod.Price, @prod.Info)">Tilføj til kurv</a>
       </article>
     }
</section>
```

Im using MVC hence the "@" from the Viewbag.
When i click the "button" it throws: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" on almost every products  tag.

It worked fine until i started adding more parameters to the function. Any ideas what could be wrong? I dont seem to be missing any ")" or escapes.

Comment: You cannot include double quotes inside double quotes without a backslash: `"\"stuff\" + \"more\""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Razorviews in ASP.NET MVC, the @ will allow you to write c# code directly into HTML. The call to the view-bag data in the foreach-loop is done with:

```
addToJSONObject(@prod.Id, @prod.Name, @prod.Price, @prod.Info)
```

However, this will not insert " or '
Therefore the correct way to use model data as a parameter (if string is required):

```
addToJSONObject('@prod.Id', '@prod.Name', '@prod.Price', '@prod.Info')
```

Answer (score 0):

You found a very basic concept called "[context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch)".

If you look at this line:

```
"@Url.Action("InspectProduct","Products")"
```

You'll find the the first `"` initiates your html attribute context. It should be ended by another `"`. However there are four `"` in between serving other purposes. Namely, they start/end a parameter value context.

There is no way for the interpreter to differentiate those `"`. Thus, the syntax error.

Please read about the problem and how you would fix it in your programming language. Sometimes it is escaping (e.g. `\"`), sometimes it is using different string literals (e.g. `'`).

Comment: The problem does not seem to be with the ", since it works just fine everywhere else i use it. For reference:  <a href="@Url.Action("About","Home")">About</a></li> Works fine. In fact, it will not accept ' instead of "

Comment: This is not correct. Please go more into the details. Observe your dome with an inspector. Also, your editor or IDE should warn you. If you look at your post's code highlighting you will notice that the green color of the @Url.Action ends after the first " and turns blue. You should take those signs more serious.

Comment: Please compare (with inspector: right click -> inspect) `<a href="@Url.Action("About","Home")">About</a>` vs `<a href="@Url.Action('About','Home')">About</a>`

Comment: I was a bit too quick there: I tried inspecting both, but it throws an error in VS as soon as i change it to single quotes.

Comment: CS1012: Too many characters in character literal. It might be worth mentioning that the error occurs in the <a> tag, where the function "addToJSONObject" is called